# Golang struct with different types and JSON marshalling

Tags: json, go, kubernetes, struct, types

I am new to Go and I feel as though I grappling with something fundamental around typing whilst trying to build a JSON payload.

- My http web app (a kubernetes mutating webhook) is returning a JSON `[]byte(string)` in a field `admissionResponse.Patch`
- The JSON returned is an array of JSONPatch and looks something like this:

```
[{
  "op": "add",
  "path":  "/spec/containers",
  "value": <SPEC-JSON>
}]
```

The problem I have is trying to build the different JSONPatch objects in a generic way.

I am Unmarshalling my `<SPEC-JSON>` from yaml files using various k8s v1 types (E.g. `v1.Volume`, `v1.Container`) which is ok, but then because each `<SPEC-JSON>` is of different type for different JSONPatch objects, I am having to create different `struct{}` types like so;

```
type ContainerPatch struct {
    Op      string `json:"op"`
    Path    string `json:"path"`
    Value   []v1.Container `json:"value"`
}

type VolumePatch struct {
    Op      string `json:"op"`
    Path    string `json:"path"`
    Value   []v1.Volume `json:"value"`
}
```

Now, when I want to put these into an array ready to Marshal back to a JSON string, they are of different types so I am ending up doing:

```
    myPatch := []interface{}{
        VolumePatch(PatchVolumes(pod)),
        ContainerPatch(PatchContainers(pod)),
        ContainerPatch(PatchInitContainers(pod)),
    }
    data, _ := json.Marshal(myPatch)
```

which works, but seems wrong?  Essentially these are all of type JSONPatch where the `json:"value"` can be different k8s objects.

How should we do these things in Go?

---update--- (thanks to [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva))

Thank you.  Reading around a bit, it seems that `any` is essentially an (empty) `interface{}`(?).  So I tried with both;

```
type Patch struct {
    Op      string `json:"op"`
    Path    string `json:"path"`
    Value   interface{} `json:"value"`
}
```

and

```
type Patch struct {
    Op      string `json:"op"`
    Path    string `json:"path"`
    Value   any `json:"value"`
}
```

... and both work ok.  I like this way as it allows me to have a single patching `func()` that returns a common type.

Comment: Your approach isn't terrible, the conversions do seem unnecessary though. An alternative would be to have a single Patch type whose `Value` field is of type `any`, then you could store both `[]v1.Volume` and `[]v1.Container` (and others) into that field, and with that single patch type you could then pass a `[]Patch{...}` to `json.Marshal` instead of `[]interface{}{...}`. But `[]interface{}{...}` is not considered wrong, especially not when feeding it to something that will use reflection anyway, like `json.Marshal`.

Comment: Thank you.  Reading around a bit, it seems that `any` is essentially an (empty) `interface{}`(?).  So I tried with both;

```
type Patch struct {
    Op   string `json:"op"`
    Path    string `json:"path"`
    Value   interface{} `json:"value"`
}
```

and

```
type Patch struct {
    Op   string `json:"op"`
    Path    string `json:"path"`
    Value   any `json:"value"`
}
```

... and both work ok.  I like this way as it allows me to have a single patching `func()` that returns a common type.

Comment: If you don't want to use `interface{}` or `any` for `Value` you should then use generic. Patch can be `type Patch[T any] struct` so `Value` can have type `T`. But this still does not allow creating a generic array of Patch though. Using `any` or `interface{}` directly is already good enough for this purpose. But in case you want to do something with each Patch type individually, generic is a better fit.